# Is $L$ compact if $\| Lf_k \|\rightarrow 0$ for Orthonormal Basis $f_k$?

Tags: operator-algebras, compact-operators

> Suppose $f_k$ is an orthonormal basis of a separable Hilbert space. $T$ is bounded. $\| (T-\lambda_k)f_k \| \rightarrow 0$, $\| (T-\lambda_k)^*f_k \| \rightarrow 0$. $R$ is the diagonal operator with eigenvalues and eigenvectors $\lambda_k$ and $f_k$ respectively. To prove $T-R$ is compact.

My attempt:

- We are given $\| (T-R)f_k \| \rightarrow 0$, $\| (T-R)^*f_k \| \rightarrow 0$.
- $R_k(f_i):=\begin{cases}R(f_i)& i\leq k\\
  T(f_i)& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$
  So, $T-R_k\rightarrow T-R$. I am not sure if $T-R_k$ is finite rank. Also I have not used $\| (T-\lambda_k)f_k \| \rightarrow 0$, $\| (T-\lambda_k)^*f_k \| \rightarrow 0$.
- Another criterion is

> $T \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ satisfies that $\|Tx_n − Tx\| \rightarrow 0$, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, whenever $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence in $X$ converging weakly to $x \in X$, then $T \in \mathcal{K}(X, Y )$.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: The space is separable.

Comment: Let $L = T-R$, Write down everything you know about $L$ and see what you can do with that.

Comment: @HansEngler Thanks for the comment, sir. Can you please give me a hint what criterion of compactness will be useful here?

Comment: Possibly approximate $T-R$ be finite rank operators?

Comment: @VinayDeshpande - $L$ is the limit of finite rank operators in the operator norm. Since we are in a Hilbert space, this implies compactness. Try this sequence of approximations: $L_n = L \circ P_n$ where $P_n$ is the projection operator on the space spanned by the first $n$   basis functions.

Comment: @HansEngler: a limit of finite-rank operators is compact over a Banach space, too. It's the converse that fails for arbitrary Banach spaces.

Comment: I must confess that I have been unable to follow through on my suggestion (cf. HansEngler's comment) above.

Comment: I am unable to complete this without some extra conditions.